# how to replcae ' _ ' Social_Science using regular expression with space?

Tags: php, regex

replace ' _ ' from Social_Science and shown as Social Science using

```
  preg_replace($_GET['category'],'_',' ');
```

where $_GET['category'] = Socail_Science coming from database

??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about `str_replace()`

```
echo str_replace("_"," ",$_GET['category']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the order and you must need to include the regex pattern inside the PHP delimiters.

```
preg_replace('~_~', ' ', $_GET['category']);
```

The format of `preg_replace` function would be like,

```
preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```